# Making an Android web app run in the background

Tags: android, web-applications, geolocation

Is it possible to make an Android web app run in the background? I've heard that Opera and Firefox allow you to do this, but I can't find a lot of material about it. Specifically, I'm making a web app that uses geolocation to track the user, then send it to a server. It should be able to run in the background while the user is doing different tasks.

Comment: For a native apps you could implement a service (see the android documentation [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)), but not sure about web apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a hybrid Phonegap app for android. That way, it can be a web app in that most of the logic can be encapsulated in HTML/CSS/JS, but you can make use of Phonegap plugins to provide the native android functionality needed to keep your app alive in the background.

Stochastically is right - you could implement a service to keep it alive in the background. But equally, you could use a Phonegap plugin to acquire a partial wakelock ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)).